# Expand-Archive // Path with special characters

Tags: powershell, zip

is there some way to pass a parameter to Expand-Archive to use Certain Encoding?
Unfortunately I have not found anything under the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7).

The reason to why I need this, is because I'm trying to zip and unzip folders with Powershell, but there are certain files that have characters like ö, ü and ä.

Using Expand-Archive replaces all these characters with an ".
Currently my command is the following:

```
powershell Expand-Archive 'Source' -DestinationPath 'Destination'
```

If Source had a folder with a file 'Störung.txt' it would extract it as 'St"rung.txt'.

As requested from Mathias, here some info regarding my system.

**GET-WinSystemLocale**

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2055             de-CH            Deutsch (Schweiz)
```

**Get-Culture**

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2055             de-CH            Deutsch (Schweiz)
```

**chcp**

```
Aktive Codepage: 850.
```

Comment: Interesting, compressing and expanding a file named `æøå.txt` works for me in `powershell.exe` on Windows 10 with `en-US (1033)` locale and CP437. Can you share your current locale and code page (`Get-WinSystemLocal`/`Get-Culture` and `chcp`)?

Comment: Hello Mathias, I updated my original post with the info you requested.

Comment: I can confirm that behavior when using `7z` (with chcp 850) to create the archive and `Expand-Archive` with LCID 1031 de-DE. What archiver/settings did *you* use to create the archive? When also using `7z x archive` this does not happen.

Comment: I can confirm that behavior when using `7-Zip` => `Add to archive…` from File Explorer context menu and then `Expand-Archive` from PowerShell. A workaround: complete **both** above tasks after setting the _Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support_ in _Administrative language settings_ (and restarting as suggested). However, doing that would destroy some other Windows tasks because it's still _beta_ feature…

Comment: @LotPings, sorry for the delayed response, had an operative procedure and all...regarding the Archiving method, I didn't use any third party at all, I simply used [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7) with Optimal CompressionLevel.

Comment: Tried setting the Codepage to UTF-8 in the Powershell session, and even several other workarounds that I found online, still the same issue, at this point I gave up and decided to just use 7zip for Extracting the Compressed File, shame that I had to resort to a third party, was really trying to prevent that...I'm still open for suggestions that don't involve reconfiguring the OS or using third party software, having an out of the box script was kind of my goal with this.